# Doesn't the publication of the Pharmaceutical Care Practices in 1998 and 2004 constitute public disclosure?

Tags: prior-art-request, prior, existing, broad, public-disclosure

In reference to the patent: [US20060271405](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060271405)

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? Public disclosure of what?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, publication of a book outlining the details of what is claimed in the patent more than a year prior to the patent being applied for constitutes public disclosure of the information and therefore the information is no longer patentable. As far as I am aware, all of the patent claims have been disclosed already in their prior book publications in 1998 and 2004.